# ASP.NET framework send token on if user exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET, so please forgive if what I ask is easy or simple.

I know how to generate tokens and storing users inside my ASP.NET application.
The thing is that I am using a SQL Server database and a table which is called `Customers`. Before all this process, I need to check in table `Customers` if user exists in my database. And if it exists, then I need to save email and password inside ASP.NET's `.mdf` file and return a token.

Also if user is making a register for first time to save him inside my table `Customers`.

Can I do that, or do I need to create custom tables inside ASP.NET's `.mdf` database?

[image: ASP.NET database]

[image: SQL Server database]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"if exists, then to save email and password inside asp net's mdf file"*. Surely, if the user already exists then they should already and an email address stored, as well as a salt and hashed password. Why would you want to overwrite these?

Comment: An mdf file is the database file for a SQL Server and is not inside asp.  To save in the database you have to connect to a SQL Server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: So i can replace mdff from asp net with my already sql server database, right?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by that comment, @Dim . A `.mdf` file is (part of) a database but `.mdf` and SQL Server database can't be used interchangably. You can't "replace" a Database with an `.mdf`.

Comment: I mean instead of checking asp net table-AspNetUsers, for email and password, to check my sql server database table-Customers (email and password). And to save, restore inside there

Comment: Thank you i figure this out by changing connection string thank you very much

Comment: One last question, if authorization will expire i need to resend email and password for generating me a new one?